# Can't install .cls in TexStudio

Tags: document-classes

I'm trying to use KDD 2017 templates. I downloaded the required file from here: [KDD 2017](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template).
I would to install the file `acmart.ins`. I opened it in TexStudio and compiled it. And this the error I get:
[image]
After it I would like to run the enclosed file: `sample-sigconf`

Comment: Why don't you install (or update) it with  your package manager?

Comment: Thanks, Can you please instruct me where can I find the package manager?

Comment: This depends on your distribution: MiKTeX, TeX Live or MacTeX?

Comment: TexStudio for Windows

Comment: No, TeXStudio is only an editor, coupled with a distribution

Comment: I have directory MiKTeX 2.9

Comment: OK. You just launch MiKTeX Update (Admin). `acmart`was updated a few days ago. Wait until it displays the list of updateable packages. As there was a recent update of binary files,  it will probably select only the main binary, you'll let the updater install it, then relaunch the updater to install the remaining files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52354/discussion-between-avi-and-bernard).